# Python iterate object with a list of objects

Tags: python, list, tree, loops

Is it possible to iterate though an object that contains a list of objects.

For example, I have the following class

```
Class Page(object)

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
        self.pages = []
```

I then create a new Page object and add other page objects to it.

```
page = Page('FirstPage')

apagepage = Page('FirstChild')

anotherpagepage = Page('SecondChild')

apagepage.pages.append(Page('FirstChildChild'))

apagepage.pages.append(Page('SecondChildChild'))

page.pages.append(apagepage)

page.pages.append(anotherpagepage)
```

What I would like to do is

```
for thispage in page:
    print thispage.name
```

And get the following output

```
FirstPage
FirstChild
SecondChild
FirstChildChild
SecondChildChild
```

So I get all the 1st level, then the 2nd, then the 3rd.

However, the following output would be find as well

```
FirstPage
FirstChild
FirstChildChild
SecondChildChild
SecondChild
```

Comment: You should look for questions about flattening a list

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `__str__`

```
from itertools import chain

class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pages = []
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(chain([self.name], map(str, self.pages)))
```

then you can just `print page`

Alternatively you can define an iterator if you wish to use your the for loop

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pages = []
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self
        for page in self.pages:
            for i in page:
                yield i
```

Comment: `__repr__` should strive to return a representation that can be evaluated to get the original object. You should instead use `__str__` for human-readable representations like this.

Comment: you could traverse a tree-like object in different ways. Some might prefer that `iter(page)` would return only immediate children and use explicit `page.walk()` for recursive traversals.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian If I'm understanding your correctly, could I use __iter__ to iterate all the direct children. And then some how do a walk to iterate though all the children.

That would be just like the os.path.walk function. I'm not sure if this will help me or not but I would be very interested in learning how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: @nerd: I've posted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13028544/4279) to show what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Do it recursively:

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pages = []

    def __iter__(self):
        for p in self.get_children_pages(self):
            yield p

    def get_children_pages(self, start_page):
        result = [start_page.name]
        for this_page in start_page.pages:
            result.extend(self.get_children_pages(this_page))
        return result


>>>>for p in page:
....    print p

FirstPage
FirstChild
FirstChildChild
SecondChildChild
SecondChild
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it recursively

```
def print_all_pages(page):
    print page.name
    if len(page.pages) == 0 then:
        return
    else:
        for child_page in page.pages:
            print_all_pages(child_page)

def print_pages(pages_collection):
    for page in pages_collection:
        print_all_pages(page)
```

Comment: 1. I don't think this is what OP wants 2. your code does not actually work. You may want check the exit condition

Comment: @KayZhu - fixed syntax errors, my b. Seems that it is what he was looking for though... can't say for sure, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, name, pages=None):
        self.name = name
        self.pages = pages if pages is not None else []
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.pages) # only immediate children
    def walk(self, topdown=True): # all pages recursively
        if topdown:
            yield self
        for page in self:
            yield from page.walk(topdown)
        if not topdown:
            yield self
```

You can replace `yield from` on Python <3.3 with:

```
for subpage in page.walk(topdown):
    yield subpage
```

in this case.

#### Example

```
page = Page('FirstPage', [
        Page('FirstChild', [
                Page('FirstChildChild'),
                Page('SecondChildChild'),
                ]),
        Page('SecondChild'),
        ])

for p in page.walk():
    print(p.name)
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/RqcqNF)

```
FirstPage
FirstChild
FirstChildChild
SecondChildChild
SecondChild
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution is both ideal and elegant.